# What is the ground state electron configuration of isoprene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, photochemistry

Also the electron configuration of [isoprene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoprene) at its singlet state and also that of the triplet state?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ground state is a singlet, when excited by UV light a $\pi\pi^*$ singlet excited state can be produced. (Singlet has electron spin paired with one electron in $\pi$ HOMO orbital one in LUMO [or higher orbital for other excited states]). The singlet may then form a triplet or decay to the ground state by emission/ internal conversion/reaction as per normal. In some polyenes the lowest excited state may be symmetry forbidden from the ground state, you will have to look into the details for each molecule.